# Error -The partition key supplied in x-ms-partitionkey header has fewer components than defined in the the collection

Tags: azure, rest, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I've created a database and a collection. When creating the collection, the partition key was a required field so I used 'Date' field as partition key.

I have created stored procedure to perform bulk documents delete from the collection in the cosmos db.

Calling the Rest API EndPoint for stored procedure, I am getting following error.

{"Errors":["The partition key supplied in x-ms-partitionkey header has fewer components than defined in the the collection."]}

Complete details of the issue is mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1191643/getting-error-while-doing-bulk-delete-cosmosdb-doc).

Answer (score 3):

The error is somewhat misleading, however in order to fix, you need to specify is the partition key for your collection using the **`x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey`** header with the request